# Javascript: Need workaround for automatic rounding

Tags: javascript, rounding, ieee-754

I have a javascript calculation to do:

```
var temp = ((1 + 0.07)^(1/12))-1;
```

The actual answer for this is:

0.00565414539

On the ^(1/12) (0.833..) you get 1.00565414539

However, Javascript automatically rounds this to 1.

Any fixes for this?

There probably are a million questions like this, but I couldn't find any on a quick google search and I've been mucking about with this for a while.

Comment: What answer yu are expecting...? 1.00565414539...?? or sum other...??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` is the bitwise XOR operator, not a `power of` operator.

You need to do:

```
var temp = (Math.pow((1 + 0.07),(1/12)))-1;
```

Comment: Oh, well that makes much more sense then.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Math.pow() function to do the power calculation instead of ^.

```
alert(Math.pow(1 + 0.07,1/12)-1);
```